# In a ring, is $a \cdot 1 = a × 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R, ×, +)$ be a commutative ring (with $1$) of characteristic $0$, thus $R$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $a ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, and let's define $a \cdot 1 = 1 + \dotsb + 1$ ($a$ times).

My question is, in this setting, $a \cdot 1 = a × 1$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sounds correct to me

Comment: As long as $R\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$, this seems correct. Otherwise it would be difficult to canonically define what adding $1$ to itself $a$ times would mean, if $a$ is something more abstract.

Comment: @Graviton On the other hand, adding $a$ to itself one time will always make sense.

Comment: Doesn't $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($a$ times) mean $a$? Otherwise what does it mean? And $a \times 1=a$ by the definition of $1$.

Comment: I wonder what "$a$ times" mean for $a = -1$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Which is why repeated addition as a definition of multiplication basically fails already in elementary school. It's a good motivating case, and it's a good initial definition, but it doesn't work in the long run (you run into basically the same issues with defining powers as repeated multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are taking things in the wrong order and that your problem in notational, in the sense that you are identifying $\mathbb{Z}$ with a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $R$ too soon, and getting confused. Let me try to unpick what is really going on.

Firstly let's use $0,1,n$ for elements of $\mathbb{Z}$; let's use $0_r, 1_R$ for the zero and identity of the ring $R$.

We then define, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ an element $n\cdot 1_R$ of $R$. (To avoid all doubt, the symbol $\cdot$ is **not** denoting the ring product, it is being defined here).

For $n=0$ we define $0\cdot 1_R=0_R$.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (and $n\ne 0$) we define $n\cdot 1_R=1_R+1_R+\dots+1_R$ ($n$ times).

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (and $n\ne 0$) we define $(-n)\cdot 1_R=(-1_R)+(-1_R)+\dots+(-1_R)$ ($n$ times), where to avoid doubt the negation sign on the RHS is the negation of the ring $R$.

It is now tedious but trivial to check that $n\mapsto n\cdot 1_R$ is a homomorphism of rings-with-identity. By "characteristic zero" we mean that the kernel is $0$ and so in that case we have a $1-1$ homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$.

Now at this stage we just identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with its image under the homomorphism: that is we write $n$ for the ring element $n\cdot 1_R$, this carries with it the identification of $1_R$ with $1$, and we identify $0_R$ with $0$ as well.

Your question is then: does $n\cdot 1= n1$ hold in $R$? We need to unpick what this actually means without the rather cavalier identifications. The symbol $n$ on the RHS is denoting an element of $R$, it is denoting the image of $n$ under the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $R$ that we have described. So thwe question is, does $n\cdot 1_R=(n\cdot 1_R)1_r$ hold in $R$? It does because $x=x1_R$ for any $x\in r$.